# Dynamical pivot table change row to column

Tags: mysql

I have schema : 
[See SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3685f/1)

but i want to make into dynamic number of username columns..
i have try with this query

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'sum(case when nama = ''', nama, ''' then count else 0 end) AS ',
            replace(nama,'','')
            )
        )INTO @sql
 from (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") as bulan,
b.nm_user as nama, 
count(a.kd_user) as count
FROM tbl_log_login a, tbl_user b  where a.kd_user=b.id 
group by a.kd_user, DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") order by a.datetime) c;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT bulan, ',@sql, ' from (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") as bulan,
b.nm_user as nama, 
count(a.kd_user) as count
FROM tbl_log_login a, tbl_user b  where a.kd_user=b.id 
group by a.kd_user, DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") order by a.datetime) c 
group by bulan');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

but nothing view, may that query is false.. help, thank you..

Comment: Try printing your `@sql` variable after the first select and see what's in it.

Comment: May be you are assigning result into `@sql` variable where  **Result consisted of more than one row**

Comment: im sorry, can your try in that [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3685f/1)`SQL Fiddle with Demo` thank you very much..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT(
            'sum(case when nama = ''', nama, ''' then count else 0 end) AS ',
            replace(nama,' ','_')
            )
        )INTO @sql
 from (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") as bulan,
b.nm_user as nama, 
count(a.kd_user) as count
FROM tbl_log_login a, tbl_user b  where a.kd_user=b.id 
group by a.kd_user, DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") order by a.datetime) c;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT bulan, ',@sql, ' from (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") as bulan,
b.nm_user as nama, 
count(a.kd_user) as count
FROM tbl_log_login a, tbl_user b  where a.kd_user=b.id 
group by a.kd_user, DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") order by a.datetime) c 
group by bulan');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

**Note:** You had space in column aliases. Space in column aliases won't work unless it's enclosed by quote. In this case I've replaced the space by underscore.

**EDIT:**

```
SELECT @sql;
```

I got this result:

```
SELECT bulan, sum(case when nama = 'Reza' then count else 0 end) AS Reza,sum(case when nama = 'Super User' then count else 0 end) AS Super_User from (SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") as bulan,
b.nm_user as nama, 
count(a.kd_user) as count
FROM tbl_log_login a, tbl_user b  where a.kd_user=b.id 
group by a.kd_user, DATE_FORMAT(a.datetime,"%m-%Y") order by a.datetime) c 
group by bulan;
```

And executing this query alone I got the following result:

```
bulan       Reza        Super_User
01-2016     1             1
02-2016     0             2
03-2016     0             2
```

**Snapshot:**

[image]

Comment: But I got results. Please see the **EDIT** section in my answer.@YanuarIhsan

Comment: yes, i have executing that query, but i wanna to make dynamical pivot table.. how can i do that?

Comment: You've made it dynamic already. All I did was fixing the issue that I mentioned earlier.@YanuarIhsan

Comment: that  SQL query has been executed successfully, but why the result is empty??

Comment: I've simulated this based on your given data in the sql fiddle. If you have same set of data there's no way to get empty result.@YanuarIhsan

Comment: i have set same, if i execute the last query(under your EDIT:) i got the result, but if i execute the first query from your answer, the result if empty..

Comment: I've shared the full execution that I tried. Check the snapshot.@YanuarIhsan

Comment: yeah i see, in my phpmyadmin = "EXECUTE stmt ;# Rows: 3"  but the result table doesnt view, how can i "print out"  or view that??

Comment: That means it's working. Try this in mysql shell so that you can view the results.

Comment: i search, dynamic pivot table doesnt work in phpmyadmin, [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667444/mysql-pivot-table-working-in-sqlfiddle-but-not-working-in-phpmyadmin).  oke thank you very much for your answer...